# Создать исполняемый JAR файл из Maven с используемыми ресурсами

Tags: java, maven, консоль, jar

Создаю jar файл через Maven и немогу решить несколько проблем.

В консоль кривоватая кодировка, не отображаются французские символы.
Файл не работает с ресурсами (config.properties) хотя в архив они упакованы.
Не могу запустить двойным кликом, хотя через консоль командой java -jar все запускается.

Как сделать что-бы файл можно было запускать двойным кликом а не через консоль, файл нормально работал с ресурсами и не слетала кодировка.

Добавлю так-же мой POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>fr.kacetal</groupId>
<artifactId>mastermind</artifactId>
<version>0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>mastermind</name>
<url>https://github.com/kacetal/mastermind</url>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>


    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}\src\main\resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>config.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${basedir}\src\test\resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>${basedir}\target</directory>
    <finalName>mastermind</finalName>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fr.kacetal.mastermind.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Ссылка на проект: https://github.com/kacetal/mastermind

Comment: Если `java -jar` запускает, а двойной клик нет, то смотреть в сторону установленных в операционной системе ассоциаций. А чтобы французские символы выводились в консоль, кодировка консоли должна  поддерживать французские символы.

Comment: chcp 65001 в Windows не помогает. а в терминале от GIt Bash такая же проблема.

Comment: А насчет ассоциаций, не совсем понимаю о чем вы. Но jar определяется как java файл и запускается с помощью "Java(TM) Platform SE Binary", компьютер что-то думает но консоль не появляется.

Comment: Значит где-то в программе выводимая строка была ошибочно перекодирована.

Comment: Логично, по двойному клику срабатывает javaw, а она не предоставляет приложению консоли.

Comment: Не совсем понял ваше предложение по ошибочной перекодировке. Ок если двойным кликом нельзя запустить консольное приложение, то как быть с ресурсами?

Comment: Данные либо "зашиты" в программу в виде литералов, либо приходят из внешнего источника. В обоих случаях у них может быть исходная кодировка, данные могут перекодироваться в процессе работы с ними (в том числе неявно) и в процессе их вывода из программы. Поэтому надо либо озаботиться тем, чтобы кодировка оставалась одинаковой по всей цепочке, либо на каждом этапе явно указывать из какой кодировки в какую происходит преобразование. Без примера кода и подробного описания вашей программы остаётся только гадать.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на проект